# MediaRecorder Chrome Codec/Container not playable on Mobile or Safari

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, mp4, codec, mediarecorder

Goal: use MediaRecorder (or else) api to produce video files that are viewable cross platforms.

Fail: current api falls back to container/codec on google chrome which is only viewable on chrome and advanced desktop media players but not on Safari or mobile devices.

! Same code when running on safari generates a working video file on all platforms.

```
    const mimeType = 'video/webm;codecs=H264'
    rec = new MediaRecorder(stream.current, { mimeType })
    rec.ondataavailable = e => blobs.push(e.data)
    rec.onstop = async () => {
      saveToFile(new Blob(blobs, { type: mimeType }))
    }
```

Tried all different combinations of containers and codecs.
also tried to override the mimeType of the Blob with MP4 file container.
No success what so ever.

also tried:

https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

Same issues. iI seems like chrome's container/codec combinations always fall back to a format that is only viewable out of the box on chrome or a powerful desktop video player like vlc.

[image]

The only cross platform working example for me is the one taken from safari browser and is the 5th from left in the picture above.

The Question:

Edit -
(We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more. Edit the question so it can be answered with facts and citations)

What is the correct container/codac to be used in MediaCapture api to make the output file playable cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue. We have tried many different combinations but always it fallbacks to `matroska`

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?  I have the same issue making videos with mediarecorder have cross browser support.  I did notice firefox have fixed the metadata issue and works fine.  However, chromium browsers are still an issue.  We've tried ts-ebml.js which injects the metadata and makes video seekable in the browsers, however as soon as you download it and play with a the windows native player it plays fine until you touch the seek handle. Then you get error: 0xc00d3e8c which suggests the video is still malformed.